# Convert XLSX to JSON

Tags: php, json, excel

I am writing a script to basically convert an excel file to JSON.  The file is a giant budget with hundreds of lines.  I used the PHPExcel library to convert the xlsx file into a csv.  I then converted the excel file into a json, but am receiving an error:

***Warning: array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements***

Here is my code

```
<?php

ini_set('memory_limit', '1000M');

require_once 'classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$excel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("sap.xlsx");
$writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel, 'CSV');
$writer->setDelimiter(",");
$writer->setEnclosure("");
$writer->setLineEnding("\r\n");
$writer->setSheetIndex(0);
$writer->save("sap.csv");


function getJsonFromCsv($file,$delimiter) { 
    if (($handle = fopen($file, 'r')) === false) {
        die('Error opening file');
    }

    $headers = fgetcsv($handle, 4000, $delimiter);
    $csv2json = array();

    while ($row = fgetcsv($handle, 4000, $delimiter)) {
      $csv2json[] = array_combine($headers, $row);
    }

    fclose($handle);
    return json_encode($csv2json); 
}

$file = 'sap.csv';
echo getJsonFromCsv($file, ',');
```

What do I need to do to make this work?  Or really just convert a large xlsx file to JSON..

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into tools like https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx2json or https://www.npmjs.com/package/j that can directly convert XLSX to JSON?

Comment: @Nirk yes I did see this solution.  I was looking for a PHP solution.  Do you kknow where I can find documentation on this, I am not as well versed in javascript.

Comment: If you install nodejs and install the `j` module from npm, it installs a `j` commandline tool.  Once you install it, the JSON can be obtained by running `passthru("j -j sap.xlsx")` in PHP